Name of part where tailgate fits into side of truck box
What is the name of the part of the truck marked with yellow bellow? (where the tailgate fits into the side of the truck box)

Image source: https://www.vitalmx.com/forums/Moto-Related,20/Truck-tailgate-trick-with-bikes-loaded-in-back,1290992

LMC Truck calls them a tailgate post (no affiliation). I don't know what any manufacturer would call it, but that sounds as good as any to help you be able to find it.
